# How can I typeset an equation with braces and conditions in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, cases

I've got the following equation

[image: Latex equation]

I've used

```
\begin{equation}
    \centering
        A_j =
        \begin{cases}
            0 & N^2 <  N_j^2 \\
            \text{must have been constrained,} & N^2 > N_j^2 \\
            \text{can take any value as long} & N^2 = N_j^2
        \end{cases}
    \label{eq:10.30}
\end{equation}
```

to write down the equation (documented here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula#Continuation_and_cases ). What is the best way to add the condition of j = 2,3,4,6,7.. in latex?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

1. Set the construction as a combined `array` in order to align the contents of the "`cases`" and the values of `j`:

   [image]
2. Use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `gather`:

   [image]
3. Set the values of `j` as part of the preceding paragraph:

   [image]

Note the difference in the placement of the equation tag (label).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    A_j = 
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
      0 & N^2 < N_j^2 \\
      \text{must have been constrained,} & N^2 > N_j^2 \\
      \text{can take any value as long} & N^2 = N_j^2
    \end{array}\right. \\
    j = 2, 3, \dots
  \end{array}
  \label{eqn:myeqn1}
\end{equation}

\begin{gather}
  A_j = 
    \begin{cases}
      0 & N^2 < N_j^2 \\
      \text{must have been constrained,} & N^2 > N_j^2 \\
      \text{can take any value as long} & N^2 = N_j^2
    \end{cases} \label{eqn:myeqn2} \\
  j = 2, 3, \dots \nonumber
\end{gather}

\noindent
\ldots blah blah blah for $j = 2, 3, \dots$
\begin{equation}
  A_j = 
    \begin{cases}
      0 & N^2 < N_j^2 \\
      \text{must have been constrained,} & N^2 > N_j^2 \\
      \text{can take any value as long} & N^2 = N_j^2
    \end{cases} \label{eqn:myeqn2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```